# How can I avoid conflicts in zsh keybindings?

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, zsh

I'd like to bind a function to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> in zsh.

```
gb-widget() { echo "geebee" }
zle     -N     gb-widget
bindkey '^G^B' gb-widget
```

This doesn't work with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>, but it works fine with other arbitrary keybindings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>x</kbd>, for instance). Maybe the problem is that <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> is already aliased to `backward-char`:

```
$ bindkey | grep -F '^B'
"^B" backward-char
"^G^B" gb-widget
```

I'd like to keep that emacs <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd> binding, though. Is there a way I can make this work?

Comment: It work's fine on my machine. Have you started from a blank config (`zsh -f` without any d'oh-my-zsh and so on!)? Have you tried with another terminal emulator? xterm and urxvt seen to work fine.

Comment: This is now works fine for me as well. I'm not sure what the initial problem; if I'm able to reproduce it I'll update this question to reflect that.

Comment: Ok, now `^G^B` works correctly, and I’m seeing the problem with a `^G^C` shortcut instead. I don't see any conflicting `^C` shortcut, so I guess that was a red herring. The `^G^C` persists with `zsh -f`. At the moment I'm mystified about what’s causing some keyboard shortcuts to fail while similar ones work.

Comment: Just speculating: Maybe `CTRL-C`isn't working, because it usually sends a `SIGINT` signal.

Answer (score 2):

The reason for the sometimes-works/sometimes-doesn’t-work nature of this problem might be due to `$KEYTIMEOUT`.

When you press a key that’s part of a multi-character sequence bound in the current keymap, zsh waits `$KEYTIMEOUT` milliseconds for you to press a second key. By default it is set to a value of 40. This is documented [in the zsh manual](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html).

So if you press `^G`, you have 40ms to press the `^B`, otherwise the two keypresses will be interpreted as having been entered separately, and not as part of one sequence.

You can obviously alter the value of `$KEYTIMEOUT`, e.g. to make it longer so you have more time to press the second key.

(Note that this can have knock-on effects, e.g. if you’re in vi insert mode and try to press <kbd>ESC</kbd> to go to vi command mode, the shell will wait for `$KEYTIMEOUT` milliseconds because there are multi-character keybindings that start with <kbd>ESC</kbd> — notably arrow keys!)

Comment: @Sasgorilla Is there any reason you haven't yet accepted this answer?